# Hatch an area in two colors with `pyplot.fill_between`

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, colors

[image: (like this, but blue and red instead of white and red)]I have a red and a blue area between some graphs. Where the two areas overlap, I want the area to be hatched in red and blue, i.e. red and blue stripes (like in the picture, but blue and red instead of white and red). So I want to pass the two colors by their color code onto the function. Is this possible with `matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between`? Or how could I do this?

Comment: Provide as much info as possible, including a minimal example, an example of what you want (even if it's done on paint). Pictures and code paint a thousand words.
Don't say "I hope it's clear what I mean", just provvide enough info so this isn't an issue

Comment: Ok I thought it was clear from my description but probably not. This is what I mean. I know how to use `fill_between` in general, I just want to know how to tell it to color the area that's filled as in the picture with two colors that are passed onto the function. (I don't think a minimal example is neccessary?)

Comment: Within your fill_between call, you can add these arguements ` facecolor="red", edgecolor="blue", hatch=r"//" `. You can try experiement with the different colours but the main thing you are missing is the hatch arguement

Comment: Yea that's sort of what I want, but it looks more like being filled red with tiny blue lines in between instead of 'half and half' like in the picture, do you know how to change that?

Comment: Can you please post a minimal example of your code and I can then help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the `hatch` argument to your function call to `fill_between`

As you have not provided an example, it will look something like this:

```
plt.fill_between(x, a3, a4, color='green',
                 alpha=0.5,hatch=r"//")
```

As per your request for the "half and half" hatch, you will need to place something like this at the top of your script, overriding the default linewidth for hatch:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt    
plt.rc('hatch', color='k', linewidth=5)
```

Adjust linewidth as neccessary.